# Facebook php sdk 5.0 next page

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, pagination

The Facebook/Facebook Class got the method next in order to get the next page.

In my case I get a list of all albums, want to loop over all albums and find the id of the cover photos album. SOme pages got more than 25 Albums, so i need pagination.

But the next method is requesting a GraphEdge.
What should I hand over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I’ll just copy my answer from the FB Deveopers group here, so the question has an answer; and it might perhaps help other people in the future as well.)*

> [I] want to loop over all albums and find the id of the cover photos album. SOme pages got more than 25 Albums, so i need pagination.

I think you can have that without pagination: Instead of going through all the user’s albums, request their cover photo – and then look what album that is in.

`/me?fields=cover` – gets you the id of the cover photo.
Then use that id to request the album – `/123456789?fields=album`

---

I didn’t find a way to merge those two into one request using Field Expansion, that doesn’t seem to work with the CoverPhoto node type (or I didn’t get the syntax right) – but still, two requests (and the first one you’d probably be making anyway, to get other user details) seems a lot better than having to loop over all albums and compare their names, and on top of that having to deal with possible pagination.